# Error while trying to create a plot for the significant predictors in my logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic-regression

This is my code:

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(log_hex_age, 
           type = "pred", 
           terms = "age")
plot_model(log_hex_age, 
           type = "pred", 
           terms = "ope")
```

And this is the error:

```
Data were 'prettified'. Consider using terms="age [all]" to get smooth
  plots.
Error in original_model_frame[[terms[2]]]:
! Can't extract column with terms[2].
✖ Subscript terms[2] must be a location, not a character NA.
Backtrace:
  1. sjPlot::plot_model(log_hex_age, type = "pred", terms = "age")
  2. sjPlot:::plot_type_eff(...)
  3. ggeffects::ggpredict(...)
  4. ggeffects:::ggpredict_helper(...)
  5. ggeffects:::.post_processing_predictions(...)
     ...
  9. tibble:::`[[.tbl_df`(original_model_frame, terms[2])
 10. tibble:::tbl_subset2(x, j = i, j_arg = substitute(i))
 11. tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location2(...)
 14. vctrs::vec_as_location2(j, n, names, call = call)
 15. vctrs:::result_get(...)
Error in original_model_frame[[terms[2]]] :
✖ Subscript `terms[2]` must be a location, not a character `NA`.
```

Comment: Can you add your data (or a data set) so we can reproduce the error on our side? Otherwise it's pretty hard to debug. It looks like you might be referencing a column that doesn't exist in `terms`, but I don't know anything about your data so really hard to say. 

Also, I'd recommend checking out reprex (https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) for sharing code. It makes it easy to check that your code is reproducible and automatically formats it for posting here.